# Converting Integer Types

Tags: c++, c

How does one convert from one integer type to another safely and with setting off alarm bells in compilers and static analysis tools?

Different compilers will warn for something like:

```
int i = get_int();
size_t s = i;
```

for loss of signedness or

```
size_t s = get_size();
int i = s;
```

for narrowing.

casting can remove the warnings but don't solve the safety issue.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using C or C++? The two are *different languages*, and different conversion rules apply.

Comment: I tend to use both and would be interested in answers for both

Comment: It depends on needs of your application, which you have not specified and also what ranges (if known) of values that the functions `get_int()` and `get_size()` return.   Generally, you need to consider those things BEFORE applying a cast.   The range of values that an `int` and a `size_t` can represent are BOTH implementation-defined, neither range is guaranteed to be a subset of the other.

Comment: @doron In that case the thing to do is to ask two separate questions since, as mentioned, the answers will differ (and would thus confuse other readers of the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [boost::numeric_cast<>](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html).

boost numeric_cast returns the result of converting a value of type Source to a value of type Target. If out-of-range is detected, an exception is thrown (see bad_numeric_cast, negative_overflow and positive_overflow ).

Answer (score 0):

> How does one convert from one integer type to another safely and with setting off alarm bells in compilers and static analysis tools?

Control when conversion is needed.  As able, only convert when there is no value change.  Sometimes, then one must step back and code at a higher level.  IOWs, was a lossy conversion needed or can code be re-worked to avoid conversion loss?

It is not hard to add an `if()`.  The test just needs to be carefully formed.

Example where `size_t n` and `int len` need a compare. Note that positive values of `int` may exceed  that of `size_t` - or visa-versa or the same.  Note in this case, the conversion of `int` to `unsigned` only happens with non-negative values - thus no value change.

```
int len = snprintf(buf, n, ...);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned)len >= n) {
  // Handle_error();
}
```

`unsigned` to `int` example when it is known that the `unsigned` value at this point of code is less than or equal to `INT_MAX`.

```
unsigned n = ...
int i = n & INT_MAX;
```

Good analysis tools see that `n & INT_MAX` always converts into `int` without loss.

Comment: The only issue is that static analysis tools don't understand the if statement

Comment: @doron, Hmmm, I have  had success with static analysis tools with the above.  I suppose it depends on the quality of the tool.

Comment: I like the `n & INT_MAX`

Comment: @doron no. Doing that discards bits silently. If the unsigned value was the amount of money I have in my bank account and it's £2,147,483,648 I will not be pleased when your banking software silently drops the top bit.

Comment: @JeremyP Just to ensure that is never a problem for you, maybe you should send some of that money to me. A mere 10% would be a good buffer.

Comment: @JeremyP Note that the code `n & INT_MAX` was preceded by "when it is known that the `unsigned` value at this point of code is less than or equal to `INT_MAX`".  That mask is there to satisfy the analyzers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in safe narrowing conversion between int types in c++ and STL. You could implement it yourself using as an example [Microsoft GSL](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/narrow).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you want perfect safety, you shouldn't be mixing types like this at all.  (And you definitely shouldn't be using explicit casts to silence warnings, as you know.)  If you've got values of type `size_t`, it's best to always carry them around in variables of type `size_t`.

There is one case where I do sometimes decide I can accept less than 100.000% perfect type safety, and that is when I assign `sizeof`'s return value, which is a `size_t`, to an `int`.  For any machine I am ever going to use, the only time this conversion might lose information is when `sizeof` returns a value greater than 2147483647.  But I am content to assume that no single object in any of my programs will ever be that big.  (In particular, I will unhesitatingly write things like `printf("sizeof(int) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(int))`, explicit cast and all.  There is no possible way that the size of a type like `int` will not fit in an `int`!)

[Footnote: Yes, it's true, on a 16-bit machine the assumption is the rather less satisfying threshold that `sizeof` won't return a value greater than 32767.  It's more likely that a single object might have a size like that, but probably not in a program that's running on a 16-bitter.]

Comment: Yet when integrating different libraries together, you will need to deal with different integer types. A simple case is the return from the write API < 0 for errors or > 0 for bytes written. We can argue if this is good API design but we are not changing it.

Comment: @doron Yes, you're absolutely right, `write` is extremely annoying in this respect.